# Can`t able to integrate strongloop with angular.js, remote methods code not getting generated in lb.services

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, strongloop

lb.services:-

```
        "login": {
          url: urlBase + "/Vendors/login",
          method: "POST"
        },
```

only this return type i`m able to get.
but it should be like dis:-

"login": {

```
      params: {
        include: "user"
      },
      interceptor: {
        response: function(response) {
          var accessToken = response.data;
          LoopBackAuth.setUser(accessToken.id, accessToken.userId, accessToken.user);
          LoopBackAuth.rememberMe = response.config.params.rememberMe !== false;
          LoopBackAuth.save();
          return response.resource;
        }
      },
      url: urlBase + "/Users/login",
      method: "POST"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

See my example on Angular with LoopBack here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-angular